# Cannot log in to ubuntu 17.10 - stopping user manager for uid 121

Tags: login, multiple-monitors

I'm new to linux and can't really follow previous solutions, because the slight differences confuse me.

I have installed linux 17.10 yesterday and everything seemed fine. I had a small problem with connecting second monitor via vga socket, and I may have tried to install some drivers but it all ended with some errors and I decided to abandon the idea. Then I found a vga-hdmi adapter in my drawer and the monitor connected to hdmi worked fine. However, when I turned my laptop on today it showed the message 'stopping user...' and I couldn't login anymore..
pls help
MacS

Comment: Have you solved your problem?